# Not able to Download files from node page on Dockerized Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am uplaoding files using forms and displaying in the table but when I click on the file to download it redirect to private ip of server but if I manually replace the private ip with public link it works for me.

Actual link- https://pivateip.com:8680/sites/default/files/2019-02/file.pdf

Expected link- https://publicdns.com/sites/default/files/2019-02/file.pdf

Comment: Are you viewing the page where the table is from privateip.com:8680? If you don't want that to happen set the base_url in the settings.php

Comment: drupal 8 doesnot allow to set the base_url, it pick up on its own, I found out the issue as I was using it via proxy server is picking up the local/private ip, when I removed the proxy server it changed to public ip, any idea how I can configure with nginx keeping in mind I have other apps as well running with nginx. @pwaterz